# Regular expression for excluding data within a certain range

Tags: shell, shell-script, regular-expression

I want to remove all the IP addresses which are of the format 10.20.30.* and whose last 3 digits fall in the range 0 to 200 and move all the remaining IPs to a new file.

I've put the IP list to be excluded in the file whiteIP.txt and its content are:

```
^10.20.30.([0-1][0-9][0-9]|2[00])
```

And my original file's content is:

```
10.20.30.150,20
10.20.30.134,20
10.20.30.201,20
10.20.30.5,20
10.20.30.250,20
10.20.30.42,20
222.233.201.5,20
10.233.201.5,20
111.233.201.5,20
```

I'm trying the command:

```
grep -vE -f whitetest.txt testIP.txt
```

It's giving me wrong result. It should give me the following result:

```
10.20.30.201,20
10.20.30.250,20
222.233.201.5,20
10.233.201.5,20
111.233.201.5,20
```

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

`.` is a special character, therefore it has to be escaped:

```
^10\.20\.30\.([0-1][0-9][0-9]|2[00])
```

`2[00]`matches 20, not 200:

```
^10\.20\.30\.([0-1][0-9][0-9]|200)
```

You have to handle single-digit and double-digit numbers separately:

```
^10\.20\.30\.([0-1][0-9][0-9]|200|[0-9][^0-9]|[0-9][0-9][^0-9])
```

This gives the correct result:

```
$ grep -vE -f whitetest.txt testIP.txt
10.20.30.201 20
10.20.30.250 20
222.233.201.5 20
10.233.201.5 20
111.233.201.5 20
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is working perfectly. 
I also want to exclude all the IPs that are starting with 10. I've written something like below in whitetest.txt.
^10\.([0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][^0-9]|[0-9][0-9][^0-9]).([0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][^0-9]|[0-9][0-9][^0-9]).([0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][^0-9]|[0-9][0-9][^0-9])

But it is giving me this result:

10.20.30.5,20
67.221.34.222,20
222.233.201.5,20
111.233.201.5,20

Leaving behind 10.20.30.5,20 line. It should not be the case. Please help.

Comment: This is working perfectly for me - ^10.([0-9]*).([0-9]*).([0-9]*)
Just wondering as to why my last entry wasn't working good.

Comment: I've edited my questions with some additional query. Please help.

Comment: @prashant1988 please don't do that. When asking here, each question should be specific and localized. Since this solved your issue, please accept it and post your follow-up query as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

This should get what you want, I think:

```
grep -vE '10\.20\.30\.(1|..?,|200)
' <<\IN
10.20.30.150,20
10.20.30.134,20
10.20.30.201,20
10.20.30.5,20
10.20.30.250,20
10.20.30.42,20
222.233.201.5,20
10.233.201.5,20
111.233.201.5,20
IN
```

Basically you just have to exclude any match for 10.20.30 with a final octet fewer than three characters, that begins with 1, or that is wholly 200.

The above prints:

```
10.20.30.201,20
10.20.30.250,20
222.233.201.5,20
10.233.201.5,20
111.233.201.5,20
```